# Add a third value to function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code which brings me only two values (key and val), the problem I have is that I need to add 1 or 2 more values in different

I'm having trouble adding two new values.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    cargaProducto();

    jQuery("#ica").change(function() {
        cargaProducto();
    });
});

function cargaProducto() {

    if (jQuery("#ica").children(":selected").val() != 0) {
        jQuery.get("<?php echo url_for('productos/VerProductosIca?ica='); ?>" + jQuery("#ica").children(":selected").val(),
            function(data) {

                var prods = <?php echo json_encode($prods) ?>;

                jQuery("#producto").empty();
                jQuery.each(data, function(key, val, val2, val3) {
                    var select = "";
                    if (prods.includes(key))
                        select = 'selected="selected"';
                    //jQuery("#producto").append('<option value="' + key + '" ' + select + '> ' + key + ' - ' + val + ' </option>');
                    jQuery("#producto").append('<tr>' + '<td>' + key + '</td>' + '<td>' + val + '</td>' + '<td>' + val2 + '</td>' +

                    '<td>' + 

                     + '</td>' +

                     '</tr>');
                });
            }
        );
    } else {
        jQuery("#producto").empty();
        jQuery("#producto").append('<br>' + '<div class="alert alert-danger" value="0">Por favor seleccione un ICA o precione el boton QUITAR FILTOS para volver a los productos principales</div>');

    }
}
```

Comment: What values are returning?

Comment: for the moment you return the code of a product and the name of the product, what I want is that you can also return the name of the user who published that product.

Comment: Christian, your data must be an array of arrays.
[]

Comment: @VladimirMiroshnichenkoAnd - how would that be, since I don't have much knowledge of jquery and this is something I have to modify.